# how to connect to a database on select of any value from combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, combobox

I have a combobox which is populated with various database name. I want to connect to a certain database on select of any database name from the combobox. Gow should I go about with this? The code for that is as follows..

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   
      {  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load("C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\Desktop\\abc.xml");             XmlNodeList List = doc.SelectNodes("config/dataSources/dataSource");    
         foreach (XmlNode dataSources in List)             
{ comboBox1.Items.Add(dataSources.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString());                    comboBox2.Items.Add(dataSources.Attributes["name"].Value.ToString());      
 }   

    }
```

I have another code with connection string information

```
public class DBConnect   
  {        
 string dataSource;    
     string userId;      
   string password;        
 string filepath;          
public DBConnect()       
  {         }     
     public string ConnectionString()  
       {    filepath = ReadRegistry("ConfigFile");     
         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();   
          doc.Load(@filepath);        
      XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes
("/config/dataSources/dataSource");        
         foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)  
     {      if (userId.select == node.Attributes["dataSource"].Value)  
               {      dataSource = node.Attributes
["dataSource"].Value;                 
    userId = node.Attributes["userId"].Value;   
        password = node.Attributes["password"].Value;   
        password = Abc.Security.Encryption.Decode(password);
                     break;         

        }       
      }          
   string conn = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=False;Password=" + password + ";User ID=" + userId + ";Data Source=" + dataSource + ";";                 return conn;         }          protected string ReadRegistry(string filename)         {             Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey theKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;             theKey = theKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Abc, Inc\Abc Marketing");              if (theKey != null)             {                 //string filePath = theKey.GetValue("ConfigFile").ToString();                 filepath = theKey.GetValue(filename).ToString();                 theKey.Close();           
  }    
          return filepath;  
       }
```

So now how should I go about writing a code which on select of any database name from combobox connect me to that specific database. I am new to c# please suggest me a solution. Where should I be including the code?

Comment: And where is problem? Construct connection string and connect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can wire up your ComboBox's [SelectedIndexChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) and when it fires you can retreive the selected database from the ComboBox's [SelectedItem property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) and use that in your connection string to connect to your database.

**Example**
You said you already have a working connection string.  All you should need to do is allow your users to change the DataSource portion of that string.  You can use  the [OracleConnectionStringBuilder.DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnectionstringbuilder.datasource%28VS.90%29.aspx) property to do this.

Update this property in your ComboBox's SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // A connection string for testing.
    string connectString = "Server=OracleDemo;Integrated Security=True"
    var builder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);
    // Show your connection string before any change.
    Console.WriteLine("ConnString before: {0}", builder.ConnectionString);
    builder.DataSource = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    // This will show your conn string has been updated with the user selected database name.
    Console.WriteLine("ConnString  after: {0}", builder.ConnectionString);

    // At this point you're ready to use the updated connection string.
}
```

You'll want to make your ComboBox use the DropDownStyle.DropDownList value so users can't type in their own database names.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder =
            new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("server=(local);user id=ab; password= a!Pass113;initial catalog=AdventureWorks");
builder.InitialCatalog = (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

For Oracle do

```
 OracleConnectionStringBuilder builder =
                new OracleConnectionStringBuilder("");//put connection string here
    builder.UserID = (string)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("Select 1 from dual", conn);
    conn.Open();
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    conn.Close();
```

Hope this help

Comment: Please verify whether you are able to connect to Oracle by code or not first.

Comment: i have to get the database name from the xml file in combobox.. that i have done. now on select of any database name , i should be able to tke the data from xml and connect to databse.. i am not getting the code for how to select database name from dropdown. by default always first value is geting selected n count is nt increasin